# Using Django Channels (websocket layer consumer) to update a webpage with data from an internal database and external an data source

Tags: python, django, django-channels, consumer

I have the following django channels class which updates values on a webpage webpage.  The class receives data from screen clicks, performs actions (toggling indicdual relays or setting a series of them for a particular use, updates a databse and then updates the webpage via a websocket layer.  All this worked fine until I introduced nina.  This receives data from a remote source via a curl POST (see below).  A curl POST results in the fail: 'TypeError: nina() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request', but if I drop 'self' I don't see how I can call 'update_relays' using its data.

```
import logging
import json

from channels.consumer import SyncConsumer
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from .models import dbConditions, dbRelays

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class DomeControlConsumer(SyncConsumer):
    """#from https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/consumers.html"""

    def websocket_connect(self, event):
        """Connects to webpage"""
        logger.debug("connected - Event: %s", event)
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            "dome_control_group",
            self.channel_name
            )   # make the group layer for signals to send to
        self.send({
            "type": "websocket.accept"
        })
        self.build_and_send_context()

    def websocket_receive(self, event):
        """recives button presses from webpage
        either 'control_button' or relays 1 through 8"""
        logger.debug("received: %s from %s", event, event["text"])
        self.update_relays(event["text"])
        # if the control button was pressed or if a relay button is pressed

    def websocket_disconnect(self, event):
        """disconnects from webpage"""
        logger.debug("disconnected - Event: %s", event)
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            "automation_group",
            self.channel_name
            )
            
    def update_relays(self, value):
        """receives values from websocket_receive event
        or nina request and changes relays accordingliy"""
        conditions = dbConditions.objects.last()
        cond_dict = dbConditions.to_dict(conditions)
        control_value = cond_dict["dome_status"]
        logger.info("value is: %s", value)
        if value == "control_button":
            if control_value == "Manual":
                conditions.dome_status = "Auto-Imaging"
            elif control_value == "Auto-Imaging":
                conditions.dome_status = "Auto-Sleep"
            elif control_value == "Auto-Sleep":
                conditions.dome_status = "Manual"
        elif value == "power on":
            conditions.dome_status = "Auto-Imaging"
        elif value == "power off":
            conditions.dome_status = "Auto-Sleep"
        else:
            if conditions.dome_status == "Manual":
                self.toggle_relay(value)

        if conditions.dome_status == "Auto-Imaging":
            for relay in dbRelays.objects.all():
                if relay.relay_label == "USB Hub":
                    relay.current_state = 1
                elif relay.relay_label == "Dome":
                    relay.current_state = 1
                elif relay.relay_label == "MX+":
                    relay.current_state = 1
                elif relay.relay_label == "AAG":
                    relay.current_state = 1
                elif relay.relay_label == "Eagle":
                    relay.current_state = 1
                elif relay.relay_label == "Heater":
                    relay.current_state = 0
                relay.save()
            logger.debug(" updated control_value %s",
                         conditions.dome_status)
        elif conditions.dome_status == "Auto-Sleep":
            for relay in dbRelays.objects.all():
                if relay.relay_label == "USB Hub":
                    relay.current_state = 0
                elif relay.relay_label == "Dome":
                    relay.current_state = 1
                elif relay.relay_label == "MX+":
                    relay.current_state = 0
                elif relay.relay_label == "AAG":
                    relay.current_state = 1
                elif relay.relay_label == "Eagle":
                    relay.current_state = 1
                relay.save()
            logger.debug(" updated control_value %s",
                         conditions.dome_status)
        conditions.save()
        self.build_and_send_context()

    def build_and_send_context(self):
        """updates webpage"""
        try:
            context = self.get_relay_dict()
            condtions = self.get_conditions_dict()
            context.update(condtions)
            context = json.dumps(context)
        except Exception as err:
            logger.exception(err)
        else:
            logger.debug("made context: %s", context)
            self.send({
                "type": "websocket.send",
                "text": context
                })

    def get_relay_dict(self):
        """get dictionary of relays"""
        relay_dict = {}
        dbRelays.setup(dbRelays)
        for relay in dbRelays.objects.order_by("relay_no"):
            relaydict = dbRelays.to_dict(relay)
            relay_dict.update({relay.relay_no: relaydict})
        return relay_dict

    def get_conditions_dict(self):
        """get dictionary of conditions"""
        cond_dict = dbConditions.to_dict(dbConditions.objects.last())
        return cond_dict

    def toggle_relay(self, relay_no):
        """taggles vlaue of relay in database"""
        dbRelays.toggle_relay(dbRelays, relay_no)

    def update_context(self, event):
        """uesed by celery task to update webpage"""
        logger.debug("got data from dome_control.tasks.py: %s", event)
        self.build_and_send_context()

    @csrf_exempt
    def nina(request):
        """RECEIVES DATA FROM NINA"""
        logger.info("request received from nina: %s", request)
        logger.info("data  %s", json.loads(request.body))
        # produces   data  {'type': 'curl.receive', 'text': 'power on'}
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'ok'})
```

```
curl -X POST awebsite.com/dome_control/nina/ -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"type": "curl.receive", "text": "power on"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

OK so the answer is to 'share' the channel_layer

```
@csrf_exempt
def nina(request):
    """RECEIVES DATA FROM NINA"""
    logger.info("request received from nina: %s", request)
    logger.info("data  %s", json.loads(request.body))
    incoming_msg = json.loads(request.body)["text"]
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
        "dome_control_group",
        {'type': 'websocket.receive', 'text': incoming_msg}
         )
    return JsonResponse({'status': 'ok'})
```

There was also a mistake in the curl request (no / at the end of the url)

```
curl -X POST https://mywebsiteaddress/dome_control/nina/ -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"type": "curl.receive", "text": "power on"}'
```